# How to detect onbeforeunload confirmation prompt answer

Tags: javascript

I am using onbeforeunload to display the prompt, cool. But I would like to detect the answer, cancel or leave.

My case is that I have a single page application, and the navigation is triggered by a dropdown. If the users cancels the navigation, I need to restore the previous selected item on the dropdown. This is the code that displays the navigation confirm prompt:

```html
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

Is there something like an event onbeforeunloadNavigationCancelled event or anything similar?

---

My current solution is to set a flag add an interval on onbeforeunload. If onunload event is reached, I know user choose to leave. If not, on the interval callback, I know the navigation was cancelled. But this doesn't feel great, but will do if no other option exist.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added the code that displays the prompt, not sure how much it can help nor what else I could provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would restore the value of the dropdown *anyway* upon firing on the `beforeunload` event. In fact:

- if the user remains, the dropdown is restored as you wish;
- if the user leaves, its value does not actually matter anymore.

Since in this scenario the dropdown is always restored, you may want to save the value that triggered the navigation, in order to know where the user wanted to go.

Comment: I have a single page application, so I need to keep the new dropdown value if the user accepts the navigation prompt (and restore it if the user cancels the prompt).

Comment: In case the user navigates away, you can set again the chosen value in the `unload` event of the triggering page or in the `load` event (or anything equivalent) of the target page.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I can hook the dropdown value to the router (using angular). This is actually a more scalable approach. Revert the value, then set it when the router navigates. I'll try this, thanks.

Comment: Ah, so you're using Angular! Of course I don't have enough detail about your code, but in this case you should try putting your desired logic upon the dropdown change event, before triggering the navigation. Relying directly to DOM events should be done only when Angular does not provide an higher-level functionality.